# jQuery: Add to html string when clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple calculator.
I have a div called result, which I have called in jQuery. Whenever I click on the button (number) I want it's value to add onto the string.
After I have a string like "5 + 2 + 3" I want to change it to an expression then return the result.

For now all I want is to add the value of the button to the string.

http://codepen.io/kreitzo/pen/RapEqp

index.html

```
<div id="calculator">
  <button class="value">1</button>
  <button class="value">2</button>
  <button class="value">3</button>
  <button class="value">4</button>
  <button class="value">5</button>
  <button class="value">6</button>
  <button class="value">7</button>
  <button class="value">8</button>
  <button class="value">9</button>
  <button class="value">0</button>
  <button class="value">+</button>
  <button class="value">-</button>
  <button class="value">÷</button>
  <button class="value">*</button>

  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var string = $("#result");
  string = "";
  $(".value").click(function(){
    string += $(this).toString();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code would let you add and calculate the expression. There are placeholders that you can use the same logic for other calculation.

```
var string = "";
$(".value").click(function()
{
   if($(this).text() == "CE")
   {
     string = "";
      $("#result").text(string); 
     return;   
   }

   if(("+,-,/,*,=").indexOf($(this).text()) >= 0 && string == "")
     return false;

   if($(this).text() == "=" && !isNaN(parseInt(string)))
   { 
       var calc = 0;
       var num
       var add = string.indexOf('+');
       var sub = string.indexOf('-');
       var mul = string.indexOf('*');
       var div = string.indexOf('/');

       if(add >= 0)
       {       
         num = string.split('+');    
         $.each(num,function(i)
         {
           calc += parseInt(num[i]);
         });
       }          

       $("#result").text(calc);
   }
   else 
   {
    string += $(this).text();
    $("#result").text(string);  
   }
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/01k9m1qh/1/

Comment: Great, do you know why the chaining isn't working when using more than one unique operator symbol? For example: 2+2+2 = 6, but 2*2+2 =4

Comment: Because i didn't implement the multiplication logic. The solution is only for addition, not for the other ones, like i mentioned in the solution and I guess that's what you asked for.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".number, .operator").click(function(){
  $("#result").append($(this).html());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery text() function to retrieve the inner text of the clicked button. At present your code is attempting to append the clicked object to the string instead of the clicked objects inner text.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var string = "";

  $(".value").click(function(){
    string += $(this).text().toString();
  });

});
```

Here is an updated Codepen that is working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwpPQY

Comment: I would think using val(); would be better rather than text

Comment: Hint: `var string = $("#result"); string = "";` is non-sense.

Comment: I'm not at a computer, but I would try something like a for each loop, taking all values and then adding then together

Comment: Try looking at the updated Codepen I posted above. The solution is working. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwpPQY

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".value").click(function(){
   var string = $("#result").html();
  string += $(this).html();
   $("#result").html(string);
   });

  });
```